# Placeholders not being displayed correctly within string

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-jetpack-compose

How can the `enum` class be altered to allow me to display values in my placeholders correctly? At present only the template is being returned. i.e. `%1$d` and `%2$d`

**Kotlin**

```
val zero: Int = 0
val two: Int = 2

// enum class ItemSizes(@StringRes val nameId: Int, val sizeId: Int) {
//    ItemA(R.string.item_a, R.string.size_placeholder),
//    ItemB(R.string.item_b, R.string.size_placeholder)
// }

// EDIT
enum class ItemSizes(@StringRes val nameId: Int, val sizeId: Int, val placeholderId: Int) {
    ItemA(R.string.item_a, R.string.size_placeholder, 0),
    ItemB(R.string.item_b, R.string.size_placeholder, 2)
}

@Composable
fun <T> MyLazyColumn(
                  lazyItems: Array<T>,
                      item: @Composable RowScope.(item: T) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn(
    ) {
        items(lazyItems) { choice ->
            Row() { item(choice) }
        }
    }
}

Scaffold(
    topBar = {...},
    content = {
        MyLazyColumn(lazyItems = arrayOf(ItemSizes.ItemA,
            ItemSizes.ItemB) {
            Column() {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = it.nameId))
                Text(text = stringResource(id = it.sizeId, it.placeholderId))
            }
        }
    }
)
```

**Current result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: You're not passing any format args to `stringResource(...)`, so it has nothing to replace the placeholders with.

Comment: To put it another way, you defined `zero` and `two`, but those variables are unused.

Comment: @CommonsWare Adding either of those variables after `stringResource(...Id)` will not work because I need to use different variables.

Comment: Right... but you have no "different variables". Your `lazyItems` does not have any additional data. Where do you expect your 0 and 2 to come from? Perhaps your `lazyItems` should reflect *all* the data that you expect to render, and then you use that additional data in your `stringResource()` call.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my code in that section. Please let me know if I have done it correctly.

Comment: You need to replace `+` with `,`. `stringResource()` takes a `vararg` for positional parameters. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare My placeholders still have not changed correctly

Comment: @nEx.Software Even after adding format args it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me and produces the expected result from your question. Note, this is basically the code you've ended up with in the question, with a few name and formatting changes for clarity/readability.

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="item_a">Item A</string>
    <string name="item_b">Item B</string>
    <string name="size_i">Size %1$d</string>
</resources>
```

```kotlin
enum class ItemSizes(
    @StringRes val nameId: Int,
    @StringRes val sizeId: Int,
    val size: Int,
) {
    ItemA(R.string.item_a, R.string.size_i, 0),
    ItemB(R.string.item_b, R.string.size_i, 2),
}

@Composable
fun <T> MyLazyColumn(
    lazyItems: Array<T>,
    item: @Composable RowScope.(item: T) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(lazyItems) { choice ->
            Row { item(choice) }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Example() {
    Scaffold(
        content = {
            MyLazyColumn(lazyItems = arrayOf(ItemSizes.ItemA, ItemSizes.ItemB)) {
                Column {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = it.nameId))
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = it.sizeId, it.size))
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```